# Running Gradlelw takes forever

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, ubuntu-16.04

I am trying to run `./gradlew :app:assembleDebug` or `$ ./gradlew assembleDebug` but my system seems to be busy for hours to download gradle as you can see in the screenshot. 
However when I build my project from within Android-studio Gradle seems to run without any problems.

I am running Android Studio on Ubuntu 16.04

[image: Busy for hours downloading gradle]

Answer (score 0):

You will be running a version of gradle that you have not run before.  `gradlew` is a wrapper that downloads the version of gradle that is specified in `gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties`.  Those dots just indicate that the, previously unused version of gradle, is being downloaded.

Comment: thanks for your answer. But why does it take forever to download this? If I download the same file through the browser it goes pretty fast.